# Crash when launching production build iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, react-native, expo

Production build crashes on launch with error

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EXExpoAppDelegate
> appController:didStartWithSuccess:]: unrecognized selector sent to
> instance 0x600001dcad60'

But everything works great on development mode. It builds and archives without any errors also. I use React-Native.

My `AppDelegate.mm`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTConvert.h>

#import <React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h>
#import "RNBootSplash.h"

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
#import <React/CoreModulesPlugins.h>
#import <React/RCTCxxBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTFabricSurfaceHostingProxyRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenter.h>
#import <React/RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModuleManager.h>

#import <react/config/ReactNativeConfig.h>

#endif

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *launchOptions;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);
  // self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];


#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED
  _contextContainer = std::make_shared<facebook::react::ContextContainer const>();
  _reactNativeConfig = std::make_shared<facebook::react::EmptyReactNativeConfig const>();
  _contextContainer->insert("ReactNativeConfig", _reactNativeConfig);
  _bridgeAdapter = [[RCTSurfacePresenterBridgeAdapter alloc] initWithBridge:bridge contextContainer:_contextContainer];
  bridge.surfacePresenter = _bridgeAdapter.surfacePresenter;
#endif
  // UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"t7travel", nil);
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  #ifdef DEBUG
    [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  #else
    EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
  #endif
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
  
  id rootViewBackgroundColor = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"RCTRootViewBackgroundColor"];
  if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
  } else {
    rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  }

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];



  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
  [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView]; 

  return YES;
}

- (RCTBridge *)initializeReactNativeApp
  {
    RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
    RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];

    id rootViewBackgroundColor = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"RCTRootViewBackgroundColor"];
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
    } else {
      rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
    rootViewController.view = rootView;
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView]; 
    return bridge;
  }

 - (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
 {
    return @[];
 }
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

#if RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED

#pragma mark - RCTCxxBridgeDelegate

- (std::unique_ptr<facebook::react::JSExecutorFactory>)jsExecutorFactoryForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  _turboModuleManager = [[RCTTurboModuleManager alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                             delegate:self
                                                            jsInvoker:bridge.jsCallInvoker];
  return RCTAppSetupDefaultJsExecutorFactory(bridge, _turboModuleManager);
}

#pragma mark RCTTurboModuleManagerDelegate

- (Class)getModuleClassFromName:(const char *)name
{
  return RCTCoreModulesClassProvider(name);
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                      jsInvoker:(std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::CallInvoker>)jsInvoker
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (std::shared_ptr<facebook::react::TurboModule>)getTurboModule:(const std::string &)name
                                                     initParams:
                                                         (const facebook::react::ObjCTurboModule::InitParams &)params
{
  return nullptr;
}

- (id<RCTTurboModule>)getModuleInstanceFromClass:(Class)moduleClass
{
  return RCTAppSetupDefaultModuleFromClass(moduleClass);
}

#endif

@end
```

Comment: The error seems to be in `EXExpoAppDelegate appController:didStartWithSuccess`

Comment: @koen Yeah, but I do not have any piece of code with `appController:didStartWithSuccess` and `EXExpoAppDelegate` either

Comment: Must be part of Realm?

Comment: @koen I don't use realm. Maybe it is expo-updates, but I'm not sure

Comment: Sorry, I meant React.

Comment: @koen oh, yes. It is part of react

Answer (score 0):

Problem was very simple. `expo-updates` library changed configuration for an iOS and there are lines of code that I needed to add in my `AppDelegate.mm`.

```
- (void)appController:(EXUpdatesAppController *)appController didStartWithSuccess:(BOOL)success {
 appController.bridge = [self initializeReactNativeApp];
}
```

For finding all configurations look at [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-updates/)